# Image source not updating dynamically

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have an Image that I have bound the 'Source' property of to the page's corresponding 'ViewModel' property named 'Capture' as follows:

View Code:

```
<Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,583,0,0" x:Name="img_FlickrPic" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Capture}"/>
```

Corresponding ViewModel code

public class SubmitViewModel : ViewModelBase 
    {

```
    private CameraCaptureTask cameraCapture;

    public ImageSource Capture { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand CaptureCommand { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Initializes a new instance of the SubmitViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public SubmitViewModel()
    {                  
        Capture = new BitmapImage();
        CaptureCommand = new RelayCommand(() => CapturePhoto());
    }

    private object CapturePhoto()
    {
        cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureTask();
        cameraCapture.Completed += cameraCapture_Completed;
        cameraCapture.Show();
        return null;
    }     

    void cameraCapture_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e == null || e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        Capture = bitmap;
    }               

}
```

As you notice, I have bound a capture button to the view model as well using 'behavior's instead of a click event in order to keep the code behind clean. When I hit the button, the camera gets invoked and once I hit capture and then press the 'Accept' button the 'cameraCapture_Completed' event fires as expected and the code in there executes. However the last step where the 'Capture' property (which my Image's Source property on the view is bound to) is set, I expect the Image to dynamically update with the captured photo. This does not happen. The viewmodel inherits from 'ViewModelBase' which in turn implements INotifyPropertyChanged, so that shouldn't be a problem. Why aren't any modifications to the 'Capture' property being reflected by the Image in the UI? Am I messing up somewhere here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually raise the ChangedPropertyEvent with property name "Capture". Something like this.

```
ImageSource mCapture;
public ImageSource Capture {
      get {return mCapture;} 
      set { mCapture = value;
          RaiseChangedProperty("Capture");
          }
 }
```